# elasticsearch return number of maching words

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index as follow

```
IDX  text                          cID
#1 - "this is a random text"      - 2
#2 - "another random cool test"   - 3
#3 - "my car is blue       "      - 2
#4 - "lorem ipsum indolor si"     - 3
#5 - "i don't know what is it for"- 2
```

I have a text to search against :

```
My very cool text is a long text with many words and random sense.
```

What i'm trying to achieve is to find how many of exact unique words in the  phrase above i have in my index with cID = 2

Expected results :
**5** (my, text, is, random, a)

Any idea to do this with elasticsearch ?

Comment: i think i should use aggregation, but i can't figure out how use it in my case.

Comment: How many terms the text to search can have?

Comment: not defined. It can be alot (more than 1000).

Comment: After some research it seems that it cannot be done using elasticsearch. Someone can confirm ?

Comment: I have a solution that can show you how many words matched in each document, but it's cumbersome for 1000+ words to search and not practical. And imo I don't think there is a solution for what you are looking for.

Comment: ok thanks. And is there any other solutions to achieve this using mongodb / php whitout looping over all documents ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongo or php. What's the use case for this scenario? Why do you want to match a big text against several small ones?

Comment: I have alot of documents for each user in my elasticsearch index. Each document contains a source and a target text. From a new file, i need to know how many words one user already have in his index.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this.

Comment: You tried to index each of your "cID" as percolator items with aggs? 
If not take a look to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html

I don't have much time right now to think a good solution, but I think you can achieve it using percolate + aggs.

I'll try later to add a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible. First, run the search with all of the words `OR`ed together, and then use aggregations to determine which words are represented. After getting the response to the query, you'll need to add up the number of aggregations with hits.

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/dockets/_search?pretty -d '
{
  "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "minimum_should_match" : 1,
              "should": [
                  { "term": { "_all": "my"} },
                  { "term": { "_all": "very"} },
                  { "term": { "_all": "cool"} }
            ]
        }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "agg_my" : { "terms": { "_all": "my", "size":1, "shard_size":1} },
    "agg_very" : { "terms": { "_all": "very", "size":1, "shard_size":1} },
    "agg_cool" : { "terms": { "_all": "cool", "size":1, "shard_size":1} }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "from": 0,
}'
```

Comment: And how do you cope with 1000s of `should` statements and then 1000s of aggregations?

Comment: The query will work with 1000s of items. What's unclear is whether it will run fast. I added a `size` parameter of 1 to each of the aggregations, so that should limit the memory that is used. Elasticsearch is pretty speedy, so it would not surprise me that this would be performant even with 1000s of terms. Would take testing to find out for sure though.

Comment: I'll add though, that this solution is obviously still `O(#of words in text)`, so while it may very well scale to 1000s of words, I highly doubt it will scale to tens of thousands or millions.

Comment: There is a default limit of 1024 queries that are allowed in should (or any boolean clause, really). It hast to be raised on a node level in the `elasticsearch.yml`, e.g. `index.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10000`. Overall, running hundreds or thousands of boolean should queries will be slow, not to mention tens of thousands.

Comment: Come to think of it, you probably do not even need the `bool` portion of the query. Just the aggregations.